# Cloud-ML Job No such file or directory

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I have submitted a training job to cloud ml. But, it can't find the csv file. it is there in the bucket. this is the code.

```
# Use scikit-learn to grid search the batch size and epochs
import numpy
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=11, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='nadam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

FIL = "gs://bubbly-hexagon-112008-ml/dataset/mixed.csv"
dataset = numpy.loadtxt(FIL, delimiter=",")
X = dataset[:,0:11]
Y = dataset[:,11]

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=1)
batch_size = [10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
epochs = [10, 50, 100, 500, 1000]
param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=epochs)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1)
grid_result = grid.fit(X, Y)
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

after submitting the job i get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in
run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/
site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 18, in <module> dataset = numpy.loadtxt(FIL, delimiter=",") File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/
site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 803, in loadtxt fh = iter(open(fname, 'U')) IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'gs://bubbly-hexagon-112008-ml/dataset/mixed.csv'
```

-The file is in the specified bucket and its permission includes cloud ml as   reader.

-I also used `gcloud beta ml init-project` to initialize the project.

-And i created a new bucket and put the file in there, but got the same error.

-My bucket is in the same region as my submitted job.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_io` from tensorflow works great:

```
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
import numpy as np
import json
```

To read a numpy array:

```
with file_io.FileIO(path_npx, 'rb') as f:
    np_arr = np.load( BytesIO(f.read()) )
    print(np_arr)
```

To read a json file:

```
with file_io.FileIO(path_json, 'r') as f:
    print(json.loads(f.read()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't read directly from gfs like that you need to use some sort of io library.

```
from io import BytesIO
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io

FIL = "gs://bubbly-hexagon-112008-ml/dataset/mixed.csv"
f = BytesIO(file_io.read_file_to_string(FIL, binary_mode=True))
data = np.load(f)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can read gcs files directly with numpy.